# Make a QR code with the "ENTER" value

Tags: qr-code, barcode-scanner, translate

Is it possible that when I scan a QR code it transalate it to me like if I hit "ENTER" on my keyboard ?

My situation :

I am developing a web page where one person scan each products code bar. When it scans one time, it add a "TAB" at the end, so it goes in the next field and soo on.
But at the end, I want that the guy, just need to scan a QR code to go to the next page. That QR code would be in the page.

Soo, is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You will need to URL encode the `\n` newline symbol.  Just use `%0A`.

Comment: Just like that :p Thanks.